# Import from Bugzilla to Redmine

Tags: redmine, bugzilla, redmine-plugins

I have a Redmine instance that is used for projects management. In addition, I have a Bugzilla instance which holds bugs/features/tickets.

Is there a way to import selected bugs from BZ to Redmine? I need this to be a repeatable task, running few times a day.

Answer (score 0):

Proper modification to some import script should do the trick.

I used https://github.com/ralli/migrate_from_bugzilla for one time import from Bugzilla to Redmine. And even though I never saw ruby before I was able to make some specific changes for our installation.

Comment: I is helpful to include the some details from the link in your answer.  Should the link stop working your answer looses value

Comment: The link points to the code on github as a example of import script possible to use. I can't imagine what could I copy from the link to make it usefull in case the link stop working other than complete source code. But as it is just an example I believe one could use google to find another import script to use.

Comment: Well, actually I've written my own code in the end. I used the bugzilla python library to fetch items from bugzilla and https://github.com/alourie/pyred which I've written from scratch to push them into redmine.